# how to save state of view in listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

In my app, I display a check list using a `ListView`. Every row in my check list is represented by a model, which is an object of the `ChecklistenPunkt` class. There are three different types of rows:

1. a headline
2. an additional text
3. a question

The third type has two `Buttons` in it which are linked by two `OnClickListeners`: The first `Button` is for a positive answer, the second one for a negative answer. When the view is build, both of them are gray, indicating that this question is not yet answered. If the left `Button`is clicked it turns green and the second one is getting a dark gray background. If the right `Button` is clicked it turns red and the first one is getting a dark gray background. When a `Button` is clicked the answering state is saved as an `ChecklistenPunktStatus`. This is an `Enum` which has three entries (okay, not okay, not answered).

Here is a little image of the `Buttons` in three rows, showing the different states:

[image]

Here is my adapter code:

```
public class ChecklisteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {

    private List<ChecklistenPunkt> list;
    private SparseArray<ChecklistenPunktStatus> sparseArray;
    private Context context;

    public ChecklisteAdapter(Context context, List<ChecklistenPunkt> objects) {
        super(context, 0);
        list = objects;
        sparseArray = new SparseArray<ChecklistenPunktStatus>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            sparseArray.put(i, ChecklistenPunktStatus.NICHT_SELEKTIERT);
        }
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ChecklistenPunkt getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        ChecklistenPunkt p = (ChecklistenPunkt) list.get(position);
        return p.getTyp();
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = null;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            switch (type) {
                case Util.CHECKLISTE_FRAGE:
                    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pruefung_durchfuehren_list_item_frage, null);
                    viewHolder.nummer = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.check_nummer);
                    viewHolder.komponente = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.check_komponente);
                    viewHolder.funktion = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.check_funktion);
                    viewHolder.kriterium = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.check_kriterium);
                    viewHolder.erlaeuterung = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.check_erlaeuterung);
                    viewHolder.io = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_i_o);
                    viewHolder.nio = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_n_i_o);
                    viewHolder.io.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            viewHolder.io.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                            viewHolder.io.setEnabled(false);
                            viewHolder.nio.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                            viewHolder.nio.setEnabled(true);
                            sparseArray.put(position, ChecklistenPunktStatus.IN_ORDNUNG);
                        }
                    });
                    viewHolder.nio.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            viewHolder.nio.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                            viewHolder.nio.setEnabled(false);
                            viewHolder.io.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                            viewHolder.io.setEnabled(true);
                            sparseArray.put(position, ChecklistenPunktStatus.NICHT_IN_ORDNUNG);
                        }
                    });
                    ChecklistenPunktStatus status = sparseArray.get(position);
                    if (status == ChecklistenPunktStatus.IN_ORDNUNG) {
                        viewHolder.io.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                        viewHolder.io.setEnabled(false);
                        viewHolder.nio.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                        viewHolder.nio.setEnabled(true);
                    } else if (status == ChecklistenPunktStatus.NICHT_IN_ORDNUNG) {
                        viewHolder.nio.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        viewHolder.nio.setEnabled(false);
                        viewHolder.io.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                        viewHolder.io.setEnabled(true);
                    } else if (status == ChecklistenPunktStatus.NICHT_SELEKTIERT) {
                        viewHolder.nio.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#cccccc"));
                        viewHolder.nio.setEnabled(true);
                        viewHolder.io.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#cccccc"));
                        viewHolder.io.setEnabled(true);
                    }

                    v.setTag(viewHolder);
                    break;
                case Util.CHECKLISTE_UEBERSCHRIFT:
                    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pruefung_durchfuehren_list_item_head, null);
                    viewHolder.headline = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.check_headline);
                    viewHolder.headnummer = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.check_headnummer);
                    v.setTag(viewHolder);
                    break;
                case Util.CHECKLISTE_ZUSATZTEXT:
                    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pruefung_durchfuehren_list_item_text, null);
                    viewHolder.text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.check_text);
                    viewHolder.textnummer = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.check_textnummer);
                    v.setTag(viewHolder);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("ViewType " + type + " unbekannt!");
            }
        } else {
            v = convertView;
        }

        ChecklistenPunkt clp = getItem(position);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        if (clp != null) {
            switch (type) {
                case Util.CHECKLISTE_FRAGE: {
                    viewHolder.nummer.setText(clp.getNummer());
                    viewHolder.komponente.setText(clp.getKomponente());
                    viewHolder.funktion.setText(clp.getFunktion());
                    viewHolder.kriterium.setText(clp.getKriterium());
                    viewHolder.erlaeuterung.setText(clp.getErlaeuterung());
                    ChecklistenPunktStatus status = sparseArray.get(position);
                    if (status == ChecklistenPunktStatus.IN_ORDNUNG) {
                        viewHolder.io.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                        viewHolder.io.setEnabled(false);
                        viewHolder.nio.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                        viewHolder.nio.setEnabled(true);
                    } else if (status == ChecklistenPunktStatus.NICHT_IN_ORDNUNG) {
                        viewHolder.nio.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        viewHolder.nio.setEnabled(false);
                        viewHolder.io.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                        viewHolder.io.setEnabled(true);
                    } else if (status == ChecklistenPunktStatus.NICHT_SELEKTIERT) {
                        viewHolder.nio.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#cccccc"));
                        viewHolder.nio.setEnabled(true);
                        viewHolder.io.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#cccccc"));
                        viewHolder.io.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case Util.CHECKLISTE_UEBERSCHRIFT: {
                    viewHolder.headline.setText(clp.getHeadline());
                    viewHolder.headnummer.setText(clp.getNummer());
                    break;
                }
                case Util.CHECKLISTE_ZUSATZTEXT: {
                    viewHolder.text.setText(Html.fromHtml(clp.getZusatz()));
                    viewHolder.textnummer.setText(clp.getNummer());
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("ViewType " + type + " unbekannt!");
            }
        }
        return v;
    }

    public SparseArray<ChecklistenPunktStatus> getSparseArray() {
        return sparseArray;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView nummer;
        protected TextView komponente;
        protected TextView kriterium;
        protected TextView funktion;
        protected TextView erlaeuterung;
        protected TextView text;
        protected TextView textnummer;
        protected TextView headline;
        protected TextView headnummer;
        protected Button io;
        protected Button nio;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

When the `convertView` is null, I create a new `View` by inflating my layout. Then I create a new `ViewHolder`, find the different `TextViews` and `Buttons` according to the `Views` `viewType` and put them into the `ViewHolder`. After that, I set this `ViewHolder` as the tag of the `View`. I distinguish according to the `viewType` again and set the text and Listeners of the Views inside the `ViewHolder`. Then I return the view.

When the `convertView` is not null I reuse the View. I get the `ViewHolder` with the `getTag()` method, set the text and Button state according to the model class and return the view at the end of the method.

My problem is that the answering state is correctly saved in the `SparseArray`, but it is not displayed correctly. When I answer a question in the first rows of my list and then scroll down, answered questions appear at the end of the list. By scrolling up and down I can mess up the answering states completely. But while this is happening, the states in the sparseArray are always correct.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: this is because listview recycles views.

Comment: Create objects for listview items and store state in those objects. And check the state in getView().

Comment: I know that, but how can I save the state to avoid the issue?

Comment: for example if you have checkbox, save state in object isChecked. and once getView is called for the cell associated with this object do viewHolder.myCheckbox.setChecked(myCurrentObject.getHasToBeChecked());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose there is something wrong with the code. When you use the same cell and when the view is not null you should reuse the same holder and not the convertView. Something like that:

```
ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    .
    .
    .
} 
else {
    viewHolder = convertView.getTag();
}
```

Comment: I updated my question to clarify my problem, please have a look.

Comment: so changing the:else {
            v = convertView;
        }
        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag(); to else { viewHolder = convertView.getTag; } doesn't solve this issue?

Comment: I removed the `v`variable from my code and started to work with the convertView directly. I also changed the code according to this answer and it seems to work.  But I don't understand why? What is exactly the difference to the code in my question?

Comment: I suppose you are always using the convertView and not the holder